# Running custom Java class in PySpark

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I'm trying to run a custom HDFS reader class in PySpark. This class is written in Java and I need to access it from PySpark, either from the shell or with spark-submit.

In PySpark, I retrieve the JavaGateway from the SparkContext (`sc._gateway`).

Say I have a class:

```
package org.foo.module

public class Foo {

    public int fooMethod() {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

I've tried to package it into a jar and pass it with the `--jar` option to pyspark and then running:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import

jvm = sc._gateway.jvm
java_import(jvm, "org.foo.module.*")

foo = jvm.org.foo.module.Foo()
```

But I get the error:

```
Py4JError: Trying to call a package.
```

Can someone help with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

In PySpark try the following

```
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"org.foo.module.Foo")

func = sc._gateway.jvm.Foo()
func.fooMethod()
```

Make sure that you have compiled your Java code into a runnable jar and submit the spark job like so

```
spark-submit --driver-class-path "name_of_your_jar_file.jar" --jars "name_of_your_jar_file.jar" name_of_your_python_file.py
```

Comment: Also, remember if you are adding multiple jars make sure to use classpath syntax for --driver-class-path and comma separation --jars.

Comment: Adding `--driver-class-path` causes tons of issues for me within AWS / EMR.  Just adding `--jars` was enough for me and fixed tons of issues I saw when also adding the same jar to `--driver-class-path` (which broke Hive and S3 access, to name a few).

Answer (score 2):

Problem you've described usually indicates that `org.foo.module` is not on the driver CLASSPATH. One possible solution is to use `spark.driver.extraClassPath` to add your jar file. It can be for example set in `conf/spark-defaults.conf` or provided as a command line parameter.

On a side note:

- if class you use is a custom input format there should be no need for using Py4j gateway whatsoever. You can simply use `SparkContext.hadoop*` / `SparkContext.newAPIHadoop*` methods.
- using `java_import(jvm, "org.foo.module.*")` looks like a bad idea. Generally speaking you should avoid unnecessary imports on JVM. It is not public for a reason and you really don't want to mess with that. Especially when you access in a way which make this import completely obsolete. So drop `java_import` and stick with `jvm.org.foo.module.Foo()`.

Comment: Using the classpath option actually worked and I can use the classes in the Spark driver. However, when I try to use them inside transformations I get different kind of errors. The option of `SparkContext.hadoop*` doesn't fit my use case. I want to parallelize a list of paths and then make a transformation that reads those files.

Comment: Inside transformations? It is not possible (or at  least not using this approach).

Comment: You can also add it to the classpath by adding it as a cmd-line param with: `--driver-class-path` if you don't want to change your config files

Answer (score 0):

If you run PySpark locally in IDE (PyCharm, etc.), to use custom classes in a jar, you can put the jar into $SPARK_HOME/jars, it will be added to class path to run Spark, check code snippet in $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-class2.cmd for details.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than `--jars` you should use `--packages` to import packages into your `spark-submit` action.

Comment: This is not always correct. `--packages` searches for Maven packages. If a user is attempting to load their own JAR that is not in a Maven repo, `--jars` is correct.