# How to access java runtime variables like java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() for pyspark executors?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The question is all there is. I want a way to check the java runtime variables for the executor jvm created but I am working with pyspark. How can I access `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` if I am working with pyspark?

based on the comment I have tried to run the following code but both approaches are unsuccessful

```
#created a RDD
l = sc.range(100)
```

Now, I have to run `func = sc._gateway.jvm.java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` on each executor. So, I do the following

```
l.map(lambda x:sc._gateway.jvm.java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()).collect()
```

Which results in

```
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

The spark context can only be used on the driver

I also tried

```
func = sc._gateway.jvm.java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime()
l.map(lambda x:func.maxMemory()).collect()
```

which results in the following error

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
```

Comment: Is it for the driver jvm or for workers?

Comment: Workers. Sorry for not making that clear

Comment: You may want to take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35725213/5761558. I was able to do something like `func = sc._gateway.jvm.java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime()` followed by `func.maxMemory()` and that returned the max memory. You just need to orchestrate that so it runs on workers (maybe using a udf or other rdd distributed calls)

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to run that.  Modified the question describing the bottlenecks